# .htaccess file doesnt allow ajax get command?

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

My problem is this code: `xmlhttp.open("GET","oy.php?antivirus="+y,true);`

`y` is 0 whatever I do. I choose one of the radio buttons . And click "Vote" button. But there is no change. `y` is always 0.

ajax and html code:

```
<script>
     function send_vote()
            {
                  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                    else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
                  var x;
                  var i;
                  var y  = 0;
                  for(i = 1 ; i < 8 ; i++){
                    x = document.getElementById(i).checked;

                    if(x == true){
                         y = document.getElementById(i).value;
                        break;
                    }
                  }



                  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                  {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                    var a = xmlhttp.responseText;

                            alert(a);
                    }
                  }


                xmlhttp.open("GET","oy.php?antivirus="+y,true);
                xmlhttp.send();


            }

</script>
<input name="antivirus" type="radio" id="1" value="1" />AVG<br />
<input name="antivirus" type="radio" id="2" value="2" />BitDefender<br />
<input name="antivirus" type="radio" id="3" value="3" />Eset<br />
<input name="antivirus" type="radio" id="4" value="4" />F-Secure<br />
<input name="antivirus" type="radio" id="5" value="5" />Kaspersky<br />
<input name="antivirus" type="radio" id="6" value="6" />McAfee<br />
<input name="antivirus" type="radio" id="7" value="7" />Norton<br /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="send_vote()" >Vote</button>
```

htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On



RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: `oy.php` is going to match your first rewriterule and get rewritten to index.php

Comment: I verified that the JavaScript code works. So it's probably as Marc says. See: http://jsfiddle.net/b6ees/1/

Comment: I don't understand. Could you explain and write code?

Comment: How can I match first rewriterule?

Answer (score 0):

Add some conditions so your don't rewrite existing files or directories:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-z0-9\-\_]+)$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: When I write document.write(y) it is always 0.